# Some index files failed to download - Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt, sudo, indexing

Running `sudo apt-get update` i get the following error message:

```
...
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca/upstream Translation-en_US           
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca/upstream Translation-en              
Fetched 3.039 kB in 36s (83,1 kB/s)                                            
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/rebecca-getdeb/apps/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/rebecca-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Moreover, finding out the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` I cannnot neither delete the file that create problem or modify that; I can only open it to see the text file content.

Could someone suggest a solution and provide some references about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following commands:

```
gksu nautilus
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list.bck
```

you can remove that file. [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2184021.html) you can find some more explanation about the solution procedure.